# Potential of a Polarized Object in Griffiths

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

I have some slight confusion regarding how Griffiths (4th ed) gives the potential of a polarized object in chapter 4. He asserts that the potential of a point dipole is:
$$V(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}}{\rho^2}$$
where $\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}$ represents the separation vector from the point dipole to the point at which the potential is being evaluated. He then goes on to integrate this over the total volume of the polarized object using the dipole density. What I am confused about is how we can use the separation vector $\boldsymbol{\rho}$ in the integral instead of the vector $\boldsymbol{r}$ from the origin to the point at which the potential is measured. In the derivation of the multipole expansion, the vector $\boldsymbol{r}$ is used in the dipole term, not the separation vector. The potential of an ideal dipole was derived by Griffiths assuming the dipole was centered at the origin and in that case I don't have a problem with using the separation vector $\boldsymbol{\rho}$ since it is equivalent to $\boldsymbol{r}$. In the case of a polarized object, however, the origin would have to be continuously shifted to the location of each infinitesimal volume of polarization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula you are quoting from Griffiths:
$V(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}}{\rho^2},$
and I will rewrite it slightly to
$$V(\mathcal A)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\boldsymbol{p}(\mathcal R)\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}}{\rho^2} \tag{1}$$

This is the potential field at the observation point $\mathcal A$ of a single dipole located at a point $\mathcal R$, and $\vec {\mathcal {AR}} = \boldsymbol \rho$.

Now let an infinitesimal volume element $d\tau_{\mathcal R}$ be around the point $\mathcal R$ in which there is a polarization density $\mathbf P (\mathcal R)$ resulting in an infinitesimal polarization $\mathbf P(\mathcal R)d\tau_{\mathcal R}$
This contributes an infinitesimal potential
$$dV(\mathcal A) =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf P(\mathcal R)d\tau_{\mathcal R}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}}{\rho^2}\\
=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf P(\mathcal R)\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}}{\rho^2}d\tau_{\mathcal R} \tag{2}$$
Now integrate:
$$V(\mathcal A) =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\mathbf P(\mathcal R)\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}}{\rho^2}d\tau_{\mathcal R} \tag{3}$$